# How to specify MaxCharactersFromEntities in Select-XML

Tags: .net, xml, powershell

similar to the question [XmlException: The input document has exceeded a limit set by MaxCharactersFromEntities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186824/xmlexception-the-input-document-has-exceeded-a-limit-set-by-maxcharactersfromen), i get an error processing a XML file in Powershell using Select-XML.

The exception is `System.Xml.XmlException: The input document has exceeded a limit set by MaxCharactersFromEntities.`.

So the solution for the C# question is to set the option MaxCharactersFromEntities, but there is no similar parameter in Powershell.

Thanks
Steffen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is not to use Select-Xml and to disable the XmlResolver:

```
param (
    [string] $Path,
    [string] $XPath
)

$xmlFile = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmlFile.XmlResolver = $null
$xmlFile.Load($Path)

Select-Xml -Xml $xmlFile -XPath $XPath
```