# MaxCharactersFromEntities Error when Loading XML

Tags: c#, xml, exception, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I am trying to upload an XML file and am getting the "MaxCharacterFromEntitiesError"- I then set the number to 1024 but error still persists - what am I missing?

Screenshot below showing the "MaxCharacterFromEntitiesError" followed by "Root Element Missing" :-

[image]

Root Element Missing Error:-

[image]

Have followed links below but to no avail:-

[DTD prohibited in xml document exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854068/dtd-prohibited-in-xml-document-exception)

[XmlException: The input document has exceeded a limit set by MaxCharactersFromEntities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186824/xmlexception-the-input-document-has-exceeded-a-limit-set-by-maxcharactersfromen)

Have added the xml file in VS as suggested but it Parses fine and no errors are shown.

Have changed the MaxCharacterFromEntities with different values (0, 1024, 9999999999) but same "Root Element Missing"  error persists...

Thanks

Comment: Try following :             XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME, settings);

Comment: @jdweng - tried but same error persists

Comment: You are still gett DTD prohibited? or just 2nd exception?

Comment: @jdweng - both MaxError then RootElementMissing

Comment: You need to get the RooElementMissing fixed first.  The MaxError I think will automatically get fixed.  The <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> must start as the first character in the file with no spaces and nothing proceeding the ident node.

Comment: @jdweng - it is formatted correctly and as a you have stated - it seems the file is too large to load - has more than 150,000 lines....

Comment: XmlReader should be able to handle the large file.  I think your xml is incomplete.  Try following to validate xml.  From menu Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste xml into view.  Error will show up in Error List like compiler errors.

Comment: Does the file actually use external entities? These days parsers often limit the expansion of external entities because of security concerns; it's probably configurable.

Comment: See updated comments